# excel vba finding with like or regex

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard

I'm writing a VBA program.
I have a problem with finding this string `[BLOCKED]` in one column

```
For j = 0 To 4
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 12).Value = groupnames(j) And Cells(i, 8).Value Like "*" & "[BLOCKED]" & "*" Then
            groupsum(j) = groupsum(j) + 1
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

The problem is I have 96 cells for this string but the program found 500 how can I do this to going work?
Thanks for help

Comment: Not sure I understand, you are getting an error message ? not getting the expected result ? it will be a little hard to help without seeing a sample of your data, and where do you set and init the array `groupnames`

Comment: @ShaiRado I think he expected 96 returns maximum, but found 500.

Comment: i have one column with datas. this datas i read to an array. i want to find every cell this string [BLOCKED] . for example one cell have "[BLOCKED] - xyz."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your **Like**  operation is incorrect.  Use:

```
... Like "*[[]BLOCKED]*"
```

**[...]** is a Character class.  So, the way you have it written in your question, it will find any single character in the set of BLOCKED.  That is not what you want, apparently.

To match the **[** character, you enclose it within a character class, as I have shown.  To match the **]** character, it must be outside of a character class.

Comment: What does *doesn-'t work* mean?  If it means you are getting the same result as before (500 matches) then you have a problem other than what you have stated. If you mean something else, understand I cannot read your mind.  Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I cannot reproduce any error based on what you have provided.

Comment: sorry.., i mean i have 0 match. if i just finding blocked i got 100matches so the code other parts is ok

Comment: I will review after you have updated your question to provide an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @SuboritsPéter Oh, and even though you entered word blocked incorrectly, `"*[[]BLOCKED[]]*"` vs `"*[[]BLOCKED]*"`, it definitely matches `blah blah [BLOCKED] blah blah` when that word is in a worksheet cell.

Comment: "*[[]BLOCKED]*" i used this for matching and firstly when i run don't work 0 match but i don't know how i run macro sencondly it is working and i've got the correct matches so thank you very much for helping

Comment: Looks like you  omitted the asterisks in your first try and included them in your second

Answer (score 0):

here is my code

```
Sub blocked()

Dim SfileUsers As String
Dim path As String
Dim pathread As String
Dim sFileread As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim keres() As Variant
Dim groupadd() As String
Dim groupnames(4) As String
Dim groupsum(4) As Long




path = "C:\Users\uids9282\Desktop\"
SfileUsers = "Users.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open path & SfileUsers
Dim hossz As Long
hossz = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim keres(hossz)
ReDim groupadd(hossz)
For i = 2 To hossz
keres(i) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
groupadd(i) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value
Next i


'fájlmegnyitás
pathread = "C:\Users\uids9282\Desktop\20170703\"
sFileread = "open.xml"
        If Dir(pathread & sFileread) = sFileread Then
            Workbooks.Open pathread & sFileread
            lastrow = Workbooks(sFileread).Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            Else
            MsgBox ("Nincs ilyen nevű excel táblázat. Kérem próbálkozzon újra")
        End If

'groupok hozzáadása a fájlhoz
Dim user As String
For j = 2 To hossz
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    user = Trim(Cells(i, 5).Value)
        If user = keres(j) Then
            Cells(i, 12).Value = groupadd(j)
        End If
    Next i
Next j

'group szummázása és átírása
ThisWorkbook.Activate
For i = 2 To 6
groupnames(i - 2) = Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
Workbooks(sFileread).Activate
For j = 0 To 4
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 12).Value = groupnames(j) And Cells(i, 8).Value Like "*[[]BLOCKED[]]*" Then 'itt van benne a hiba!!         groupsum(j) = groupsum(j) + 1
        End If
    Next i
Next j
ThisWorkbook.Activate
For j = 2 To 6
    Cells(j, 4).Value = groupsum(j - 2)
Next j

Workbooks(SfileUsers).Close SaveChanges:=False
Workbooks(sFileread).Close SaveChanges:=True


End Sub
```

[this is my excel file where i want to searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if3jj.jpg)

Comment: This belongs as an update to your question (edit your question to include this) as it is not an answer to your question.  Also, I do not have a tool to convert the screenshot of your Excel page to a usable Excel worksheet. What tool do you use to accomplish that conversion?